# How to open application using paired bluetooth device's data in broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, bluetooth

My application is use obd scanner(which is provide bluetooth interface) for get car data. I want to add one feature in this application which is app should be open itself whenever car's obd(already paired) in range of mobile's bluetooth.

My thoughts for implementing this are getting list of paired device in broadcast receiver if any of pair device contain sub-string obd(small or capital)then app should open itself.

what I had achieved :
    whenever any bluetooth device which contain obd Sub string is connected with my mobile my app is open itself.process of connection is manually done by me by device setting.

**code inside broadcast for above mentioned result:**

```
public class BrodcastBlueTooth extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BrodcastBlueTooth() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String DeviceName=null;
        String action = intent.getAction();
//        Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Action "+action+"received");
        int state;
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

        switch(action)
        {

            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:
                bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connected to "+bluetoothDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Connected to "+bluetoothDevice.getName());

                DeviceName=bluetoothDevice.getName();
                if (DeviceName.contains("OBD")){
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
                    newIntent.setClassName("com.quad14.obdnewtry", "com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.MainActivity");
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    context.startActivity(newIntent);


                }else if(DeviceName.contains("obd")){
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
                    newIntent.setClassName("com.quad14.obdnewtry", "com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.MainActivity");
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    context.startActivity(newIntent);
                }

                break;

            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED:
                bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected from "+bluetoothDevice.getName(),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
```

I am declaring my broadcast in manifest so it's always working in background.

**I got the paired device list by below code:**

```
   public void PairedDevice(){
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    PaiedDevices.add(device.getName());

                    Log.e("DeviceName", String.valueOf(PaiedDevices));
                    PairDeviceFlag=true;
                }
            }
        }
```

what should i do from this point to get desired result. any other ways also welcome.

Comment: From information provided it is not possible to identify what your problem is. Do you want to create a bluetooth background scanner and use it to find specific device and then launch an app? What is the problem?

Comment: @Tomas I don't know on which event Broadcast receiver should get pair device. One possible way i can think is on every 10 sec broadcast receiver should be checking if paired device is  in range or not. I don't know  which kind of thread should i implement for achieve this. I don't know how to consistently provide paired list inside that thread which inside broadcast receiver.